# Deducing this inequality from Cauchy-Schwarz?

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have the inequality $$ \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - y_k)^2} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k - z_k)^2} + \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n (z_k - y_k)^2}. $$

The hint says this follows from Cauchy Schwarz, but I don't see how. Cauch-Schwarz says we have $$| \langle x, y\rangle | \leq || x || \cdot || y ||. $$ How can I use that here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the triangle inequality in $\mathbb R^n$! In general you can prove the triangle inequality using Cauchy-Schwarz in any space where the norm arises from the inner product (that is, $||x||^2 = \langle x,x\rangle$; clearly $\mathbb R^n$ is such a space). See for example the wikipedia entry on  [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Normed_vector_space).

Now let $||\cdot||$ be the usual norm in $\mathbb R^n$ and $(\cdot, \cdot)$ be the usual inner product. Then you can show it as follows:

$$||x+y||^2 = (x+y,x+y) \le ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 + 2|(x,y)|\le ||x||^2 + ||y||^2 + 2||x||\cdot ||y|| = (||x|| + ||y||)^2$$ where we used the Cauchy Scwarz inequality on the penultimate step.

So we showed $||x+y|| \le ||x|| + ||y||$; hence you can write

$$||x-y|| = ||x-z + z-y|| \le ||x-z|| + ||z-y||$$

which is what you wanted to prove.

Note that *complete* metric spaces where the norm is generated by the inner product are called [Hilbert spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space). They are especially important and used everywhere